# python - Error in displaying the correct images for the spectrum of certain functions

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a Python code that generates images and their spectra for five different functions, but there's an issue where functions 2 to 5 produce a black image for the spectrum instead of the desired output.

The problem:

```py
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  magnitude_spectrum_2 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_2))
```

Same for signal_3-5.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dimensiunile imaginii
M, N = 256, 256

# Generare coordonate n1, n2
n1 = np.arange(0, M)
n2 = np.arange(0, N)
n1, n2 = np.meshgrid(n1, n2)

# Definirea celor cinci funcții date
def signal_function_1(n1, n2):
    return np.sin(2 * np.pi * n1 + 3 * np.pi * n2)

def signal_function_2(n1, n2):
    return np.sin(4 * np.pi * n1) + np.cos(6 * np.pi * n2)

def signal_function_3(n1, n2):
    Y = np.zeros_like(n1, dtype=complex)
    Y[0, 5] = Y[0, N-5] = 1
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft2(Y))

def signal_function_4(n1, n2):
    Y = np.zeros_like(n1, dtype=complex)
    Y[5, 0] = Y[N-5, 0] = 1
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft2(Y))

def signal_function_5(n1, n2):
    Y = np.zeros_like(n1, dtype=complex)
    Y[5, 5] = Y[N-5, N-5] = 1
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft2(Y))

# Calculul semnalelor
signal_1 = signal_function_1(n1, n2)
signal_2 = signal_function_2(n1, n2)
signal_3 = signal_function_3(n1, n2)
signal_4 = signal_function_4(n1, n2)
signal_5 = signal_function_5(n1, n2)

# Calculul DFT bidimensional
dft_signal_1 = np.fft.fft2(signal_1)
dft_signal_2 = np.fft.fft2(signal_2)
dft_signal_3 = np.fft.fft2(signal_3)
dft_signal_4 = np.fft.fft2(signal_4)
dft_signal_5 = np.fft.fft2(signal_5)


magnitude_spectrum_1 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_1))
magnitude_spectrum_2 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_2))
magnitude_spectrum_3 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_3))
magnitude_spectrum_4 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_4))
magnitude_spectrum_5 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_5))


# Vizualizare pentru prima funcție
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(signal_1, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Imagine 1')
plt.subplot(222), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum_1), plt.title('Spectru 1')

# Vizualizare pentru a doua funcție
plt.subplot(223), plt.imshow(signal_2, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Imagine 2')
plt.subplot(224), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum_2), plt.title('Spectru 2')

plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
# Vizualizare pentru a treia funcție
plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(signal_3, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Imagine 3')
plt.subplot(222), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum_3), plt.title('Spectru 3')

plt.show()

# Vizualizare pentru a patra funcție
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(signal_4, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Imagine 4')
plt.subplot(222), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum_4), plt.title('Spectru 4')

# Vizualizare pentru a cincea funcție
plt.subplot(223), plt.imshow(signal_5, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Imagine 5')
plt.subplot(224), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum_5), plt.title('Spectru 5')

plt.show()
```

I tried to solve the issue, but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid division by zero error, you can calculate the logarithm only for non-zero samples:

```
magnitude_spectrum_1 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_1), where=dft_signal_1 > 0)
magnitude_spectrum_2 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_2), where=dft_signal_2 > 0)
magnitude_spectrum_3 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_3), where=dft_signal_3 > 0)
magnitude_spectrum_4 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_4), where=dft_signal_4 > 0)
magnitude_spectrum_5 = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(dft_signal_5), where=dft_signal_5 > 0)
```

Another solution is to add very small constant value to all of signal samples.

Comment: I tried your solution, and it displays 4 purple images, indicating that it doesn't generate the images correctly.

Comment: @CaruntuRazvan it *does* create them correctly, those are not only purply images, note yellow dots in the top left corner. If you think such a spectrum is not correct, then your problem is wrong signal, not wrong display of spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing logarithm of 0 that gives you -Inf, not plottable.

Add small number before computing logarithm, for example one milionth of the spectrum maxiumum

```
abs_spectrum1 = np.abs(dft_signal_1)
magnitude_spectrum_1 = 20 * np.log10(abs_spectrum1  + np.max(abs_spectrum1) / 1_000_000)
abs_spectrum2 = np.abs(dft_signal_2)
magnitude_spectrum_2 = 20 * np.log10(abs_spectrum2  + np.max(abs_spectrum2) / 1_000_000)
abs_spectrum3 = np.abs(dft_signal_3)
magnitude_spectrum_3 = 20 * np.log10(abs_spectrum3  + np.max(abs_spectrum3) / 1_000_000)
abs_spectrum4 = np.abs(dft_signal_4)
magnitude_spectrum_4 = 20 * np.log10(abs_spectrum4  + np.max(abs_spectrum4) / 1_000_000)
abs_spectrum5 = np.abs(dft_signal_5)
magnitude_spectrum_5 = 20 * np.log10(abs_spectrum5  + np.max(abs_spectrum5) / 1_000_000)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and it displays 4 purple images, indicating that it doesn't generate the images correctly.